# Previously published APIs not visible after pod restart

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have set up API Manager on Azure using the helm charts provided in [am-pattern-1](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/tree/master/advanced/am-pattern-1). I have also set up a Persistent Volume backed by an Azure file share in order for the files located in `~/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/deployment/server/executionplans` and `~/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs` to survive restarts.

However, when I restart my pod (or `helm uninstall/helm install` API manager), the UI (devportal or publisher) always comes up with an empty screen for the list of published APIs. Given the set up I would expect API Manager to display the APIs that were previously published.

When the pod comes up, I can see in the logs that API Manager "found" those APIs, but still was not able to display them:

```
[2021-04-07 16:00:26,705]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : EricTest4--v1.0_APIproductionEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2021-04-07 16:00:26,721]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : EricTest4--v1.0_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2021-04-07 16:00:26,738]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : EricTest5--v1.0_APIproductionEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
[2021-04-07 16:00:26,754]  INFO - DependencyTracker Endpoint : EricTest5--v1.0_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
```

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround or fix? I am using API Manager 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The API Manager uses Solr indexes to display the APIs in both Publisher and Devportal. The AM-Pattern-01 Helm chart comes with MySQL configurations in place along with separate volume mounts for Solr indexes.

An empty page can be observed, if the Solr indexes are not completed properly or if the configured Registry DBs (`SHARED_DB`) are having inconsistent entries related to API artifacts.

As an option, you can configure the following in `deployment.toml` of the API Manager and restart the servers. This is to re-index the artifacts.

```
[indexing]
re_indexing = 1
```